# gpg encrypt file without keyboard interaction

Tags: bash, cron, gnupg

I am running next command within a crontab to encrypt a file and I don't want a keyboard interaction

```
echo "PASSPHRASE" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -r USER --encrypt FILENAME.TXT
```

but I have this answer:

```
gpg: C042XXXX: There is no assurance this key belongs to the named user

pub  40XXX/C042XXXX 2012-01-11 Name LastName. (comment) <user@email.com>
 Primary key fingerprint: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX
      Subkey fingerprint: XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX  XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX

It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named
in the user ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing,
you may answer the next question with yes.

Use this key anyway? (y/N)
```

Comment: Since --passphrase-fd reads only the first line... what happens if you run `echo -e "PASSPHRASE" "\nyes" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 -r USER --encrypt FILENAME.TXT` ?

Comment: man page anyone? `--batch` and `--yes`.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As David intimated, the problem here is that gpg doesn't trust the public key you're using to encrypt. You could sign the key as he explained.

An alternative--especially if the key might be changing occasionally--would be to tack on `--trust-model always` to your gpg command.

Here's the relevant bit from the man page:

> ```
> --trust-model pgp|classic|direct|always|auto
>
>      Set what trust model GnuPG should follow. The models are:
>
>      pgp    This is the Web of Trust combined with trust signatures as used in
>             PGP 5.x and later. This is the default trust model when creating a
>             new trust database.
>
>      classic
>             This is the standard Web of Trust as used in PGP 2.x and earlier.
>
>      direct Key validity is set directly by the user and  not  calculated  via
>             the Web of Trust.
>
>      always Skip  key  validation  and  assume that used keys are always fully
>             trusted. You generally won't use this unless you  are  using  some
>             external  validation  scheme.  This  option  also  suppresses  the
>             "[uncertain]" tag printed with signature checks when there  is  no
>             evidence that the user ID is bound to the key.
>
>      auto   Select  the  trust  model depending on whatever the internal trust
>             database says. This is  the  default  model  if  such  a  database
>             already exists.
> ```

Comment: Don't understand why the system thinks that's code. I clicked quote; not code. When editing it shows up only as quoted (with no color). Weird.

Comment: it's because the text uses spaces to align.

Comment: this is the correct answer for me! thank you

Answer (score 46):

Here is my solution, based on gpg2 (but I bet you can apply similar technique to gpg)

```
$ gpg2 --edit-key {recipient email address}  
> trust
> 5 (select 5 if you ultimately trust the key) 
> save
```

This will tell gpg2 to trust the key fully, so that you can encrypt without prompt

Comment: This updates the trust-db immediately and no save is required.

Comment: This sets the owner-trust not the key-validity. Ultimate Trust is only for your own Keys. i.e. Everything signed by an Ultimately Trusted Identity is handled as signed by your self. So DO NOT SET TRUST TO ULTIMATE if it is not your key.

The problem is the key-validity. To solve/workaround this you should sign the key. (consider a local-only signature and fingerprint verification)

Comment: x539 is right. after `gpg2 --edit-key <key-id>` you do **`lsign`** and `save`. I think the trust 5 is wrong use for this (misunderstood), and (for me) it was even ineffective (useless), becuase what x539 told.

Comment: Note that this also works for normal `gpg`, not only for `gpg2` :)

Answer (score 11):

The hack approach:

```
echo -n PASSPHRASE > phrase
chmod 400 phrase #Make sure ONLY the user running the cron job can read the phrase
yes | gpg --passphrase-fd 3 --recipient USER --encrypt FILENAME.txt 3<phrase
```

The underlying problem is that the key you have for USER isn't signed. If you trust it, you can sign it with

```
gpg --edit-key USER sign
```

It will probably ask a couple questions, depending on your configuration. Do this once, then you should be good to go in your crontab. I'd still recommend using the solution I proposed, putting the passphrase in a separate file and making it only readable by the one user that command runs as. If you do that, you can kill the `yes |`, and just have the encrypt line.

Comment: I tried the sign key method, both gpg2 --edit-key USER sign, now it shows that it is signed, but still trust:unknown.  And the batch still will not run w/o prompting

Comment: I think `lsign` would be a better idea. Is it not that if you lsign ie. locally sign a key, that sign stays on your computer. But if you simply sign, that's considered public, and thus would be sent to keyservers when you do a `--send-keys` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use this command, it will help you

```
echo "PASSPHRASE" | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --always-trust -r USER --encrypt FILENAME.TX
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this too. I couldn't get sign-key to do anything interesting. Here's what I did:

create a gpg key:

```
gpg --gen-key
```

get long key ID (result is in 5th column):

```
gpg --list-keys --with-colon name@domain.tld
```

Add trusted key line to ~/gnupg/gpg.conf

```
trusted-key 16DIGITALPHANUMERICKEYID
```

gpg line in backup script:

```
gpg -e -r name@domain.tld backup_file.tgz
```

Debugging cron:
I'm also capturing cron dubugging output by sending stdout and stderr to a log file in the cron command line. It's helpful to know

Comment: No, don't do that. Adding a `trusted-key` line to `gpg.conf` will cause `gpg` to _always_ trust that key _as fully as one of the user's own keys_, [which is a bad thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9460140#comment38816101_14658006). Passing `--trusted-key` as an _argument_, and only in _this specific case_ is acceptable (as is [passing `--trust-model=always` in the same way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9466566)).

Comment: It is my key. Isn't marking it as trusted exactly what I want?

Comment: If it's _actually_ your key, then yes, mark it as ultimately trusted (though I personally prefer to do that with `--edit-key`, not by adding a `trusted-key` line). The asker didn't say that it was _their own_ key that `gpg` was complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that like me, a lot of people come here for the 'without keyboard interaction' part of the question. With gpg2 and gpg-agent it got quite complicated to sign/encrypt/decrypt stuff without any keyboard interaction. Here is how you would create a signature when your plaintext private key passphrase is saved in a text file:

```
cat something_so_sign.xzy | gpg \
    --passphrase-file "plaintext_passphrase.txt" \
    --batch \
    --pinentry-mode loopback \
    -bsa
```

Change -b -s -a depending on your needs. The other switches are mandatory. You may also just use `--passphrase 'SECRET'`. As already pointed out, be careful with that. Plaintext textfiles are not that much better of course.

Answer (score 0):

Or sign the key (after you veryfied the fingerprint, of course):

```
gpg --sign-key <recipient email address>
```

After that you fully trust the key.

```
  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
```

Comment: Trusting the owner has nothing to do with this problem. Only set the owner trust if you trust him in regard to signing/verifying other keys and their owners

Comment: Ianes why not edit your answer to update about key trust? Currently may be misleading... Also `--lsign-key` may be a better idea, no? see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460140/gpg-encrypt-file-without-keyboard-interaction#comment57479879_9466332) about lsign

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you create a certificate first time with your email-id select fully trusted certificate then whenever you encrypt any file will not ask question like.... for more information open image in above link.

> It is NOT certain that the key belongs to the person named in the user
>   ID.  If you *really* know what you are doing, you may answer the next
>   question with yes.
>
> Use this key anyway? (y/N)

Answer (score 0):

**A different approach:**

This solution will work without user input.

To ***deny access*** to sensitive data (rather than encrypt it using third-party's keys), I upload **ONLY* my **PUBLIC** key to the server I want to protect data on and use that key to encrypt with. This negates the need for an interactive prompt to supply a password facilitating automation and best of all, the **PRIVATE** key is apart from the public server.

```
gpg --batch --yes --trust-model always -r $YOURPUBKEYEMAILADDRESS -e ./file.txt
```

However, if **NOT** encrypting with your own public key, the use of the switch `--trust-model always` is a bit ropey.  Anyway, a different way of solving the problem of denying access to data. HTH- Terrence Houlahan