# How to generate encrypted doc using gnupg via command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption, cmd, gnupg

I need some assistance to generate encrypted documents using https://www.gnupg.org/ software.

They have provided the command line as per following.

```
alice% gpg --output doc.gpg --encrypt --recipient blake@cyb.org doc
```

But I am not getting as per my file structure how I am suppose to do same.

Please check the following file structure.

Public Key      : C:\Encryption\PB_Key.asc

File need to encrypt    : C:\Encryption\Test.txt

Bat file        : C:\Encryption\Test.bat

gpg.exe         : C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe

UserName        : Test

I did some research and found few links

[Batch encrypt with public key using Gpg4win command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305319/batch-encrypt-with-public-key-using-gpg4win-command-line)

Need assistance to incorporate above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
@echo off
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
gpg  --import PB_Key.asc
gpg  -r "Test" -e "C:\Encryption\Test.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create a batch file as following.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" --import PB_Key.asc
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" -r "Test" -e "C:\Encryption\Test.txt"
```